# Nonclustered index with include vs nearly same Nonclustered index without; Multiple query coverage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have two existing indices in a DB as below

1. CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IndexTable1
        ON Table (fkAnothertable)
2. CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IndexTable2
        ON Table (fkAnothertable)
                INCLUDE (pkTable)

I had a hunch and my research seems to point that any queries that call #1 would be satisfied by #2 and that #1 is wasteful. I couldn't find a definitive answer though.

Is this assumption correct and can I drop #1 and potentially improve performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. #2 entirely covers #1 and possibly vice-versa in fact. Is `pkTable` your clustered index key? If so that will be included in #1 (at the key level because the non clustered index is not declared as unique).

If `pkTable` is not the clustering key then queries seeking on `#1` will still be satisfied by `#2` but `#2` may occupy more pages thus making scans that would have used `#1` a tad less efficient.

Comment: I don't believe we actually have any clustered indexes. I could be wrong though. Let me check and get back to you on that.

Comment: @user526999 - The PK is backed up by a clustered index unless you explicitly specify otherwise.

Comment: Yes it is, just wasn't in the .sql file I was given.

Comment: I am noob if you can't tell. So let me see if I understand #1 will be covering #2 if the clustered index covers the "Include". This is because the nonclustered simply points at the location in the table which is sorted by the clustered index which contains my include?

Comment: @Wulfhart On a table with a Clustered Index the row locator used in the NCIs is the clustered index key. Whether this row locator ends up in the NCI key or just as an included column in the leaf pages depends on whether or not the non clustered index is declared as unique or not. This is [explained well here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. That page clears some other questions up too.